# How to clear fields array in redux form

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I am trying to clear checkbox array in fields array from the redux form. How can I do it?

I'm using redux form FieldArray in the format of `members:[filterOption:{}, checkBoxOption:{}]`. `checkBoxOption` value depends o `filterOption` dropdown. Whenever the user selects an option from `filterOption` in result they get a list of checkbox from which they have to select from the list of `checkBoxOption`.

[image: redux store]

Let's say if a user has selected a value from `filterOption` and `checkBoxOption` and now they change the value of `filterOption` in result they will get a new list of an array for `checkBoxOption`. The values are getting replaced by the new one but they are not getting uncheck.

I am able to clear checkbox array in values array by using `fields.get(event).checkBoxOption = {}` but unable to find the solution on how to empty fields array.

Can anyone help me out with this?

```
<ul className="list-group">
      {
        fields.map((member, index) => (
          <li className="list-group filter-select-box" key={index}>
            <SelectBox
              name={`${member}.filterOption`}
              label="Metadata Attribute"
              options={attributes.map(attribute => ({
                value: attribute.name,
                label: attribute.name,
                disabled: selectedAttributes.filter(value => value.name === attribute.name).length > 0,
              }))}
              isChange
              handleSelectChange={opt => handleOptionChange(index, opt.value)}
            />
            {checkStatus(index) && (
              <div className="select-checkbox-option form-group">
                {
                  getCheckboxList(index).map((checkboxItem, x) => (
                    <CheckBox
                       key={x}
                       type="checkbox"
                       name={`${member}.checkBoxOption.${checkboxItem}`}
                       label={checkboxItem}
                       value={`${member}.checkBoxOption.${checkboxItem}`}
                       id={checkboxItem}
                    />
                  ))
                }
              </div>
            )}
          </li>
        ))
      }
      <li className="list-group filter-select-box">
        <button className="add-filter" type="button" onClick={() => fields.push({})}>
          <img src={filterPlus} alt="" className="filterPlus" />
          Add Filter
        </button>
        {touched && error && <span>{error}</span>}
      </li>
    </ul>
```

the function which is getting checkbox value

```
const handleOptionChange = (event, nameAttribute) => {
    const value = {
      index: event,
      status: true,
      name: nameAttribute,
    };

    let selectedAttributesStatus = false;
    for (let i = 0; i < selectedAttributes.length; i += 1) {
      if (value.index === selectedAttributes[i].index) {
        selectedAttributes[i].name = value.name;
        selectedAttributesStatus = true;
      }
    }

    if (!selectedAttributes.length || !selectedAttributesStatus) {
      setSelectedAttributes([...selectedAttributes, value]);
    }

    setShowOptions([...showOption, value]);
    getCategoricalVar(extractorId, nameAttribute)
      .then((resp) => {
        const newAttributeValue = {
          index: event,
          value: resp,
        };
        fields.get(event).checkBoxOption = {};
        setSelectedIndex(false);
        console.log('fields.get(event).checkBoxOption: ', fields.get(event).checkBoxOption);
        let attributeValuesStatus = false;
        for (let i = 0; i < attributeValues.length; i += 1) {
          if (newAttributeValue.index === attributeValues[i].index) {
            attributeValues[i].value = newAttributeValue.value;
            attributeValuesStatus = true;
          }
        }
        if (!attributeValues.length || !attributeValuesStatus) {
          setAttributeValues([...attributeValues, newAttributeValue]);
        }
      })
      .catch(printError);
  };
```

Function which is setting the value on checkbox

```
const getCheckboxList = (index) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < attributeValues.length; i += 1) {
      if (attributeValues[i].index === index) {
        return attributeValues[i].value;
      }
    }
    return [];
  };
```

Comment: Please include some code

Comment: @Dario Done. Check it now